# Add two contingency tables in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I am building a recommendation system for which I am building a contingency table to understand the association between the products.

My contingency table looks as below, say Tble-1 :

```
   a  b  c  d
a  2  1  1  1
b  1  2  2  0
c  1  2  2  0
d  1  0  0  1
```

It is a pandas data frame.

Since I am working on streaming data, I need to update this contingency table whenever I get new data.

Assume I get new contingency Table, say Table-2:

```
   a  b  c  e
a  2  1  1  4
b  1  1  2  0
c  1  2  4  2
e  1  3  0  4
```

I need to add the two contingency Tables i.e., Table-1 + Table-2 which results in a new table as follows:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
a  4  2  2  1  4
b  2  3  4  0  0
c  2  4  6  1  4
d  1  0  0  1  0
e  1  3  0  0  4
```

How can I achieve this in python pandas?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You want to know how you can edit a dataframe?

Comment: what is you update value ?

Comment: Question Edited @Wen-Ben

Comment: Added more info in Question @NoSplitSherlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with parameter `fill_value=0` for non matched values, then replace non exist values and convert to integer, if necessary:

```
df = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e
a  4  2  2  1  4
b  2  3  4  0  0
c  2  4  6  0  2
d  1  0  0  1  0
e  1  3  0  0  4
```